# Button size on different Android screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout, which has only 2 widgets: a full screen `ImageView` as background and a `Button`. The background has no problem, however, I failed to position & resize the button to fit in all screens. The button is supposed to be located at 2/3 of the screen, center-aligned.

Here is my `activity_login.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hk.goodsight.kitchenlifestyle.LoginActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_signin"
        android:contentDescription="background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_signin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From other SO questions, some recommend the followings:

1. Convert px to dp, in order to calculate the size and position of the button
2. Use different layout for different screen sizes

Which should I choose?

p.s. has to support Android 4.0, thus I cannot use percentage as margin bottom, which is introduced in API 23.

Comment: have you tried using layout_weight?

Comment: Yes, tried `layout_weight`. As there is no other element, `layout_weight` is unable to calculate the correct position.

Comment: Posted one solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little naive method I guess, but I have tested this preview on many devices and it shows what you want. Instead of an `ImageView`, I have set the image background on the parent layout. Replace the value with your original image resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="blah"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"/>
```

Comment: You hinted me. I ended up using `Space` instead of `LinearLayout` which has simpler logic.

Comment: Good to know you have achieved what you wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the display size from the WindowManager and then set the Button margin top to be 2/3 fraction of it programatically ,something like:

```
android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    params.setMargins(0,(int)(display.getHeight()*0.666),0,0);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```